# Scanning and listing files recursively without os.walk()

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, directory

I'm new to programming and have been learning Python for around a month as my first language into information security. In a course, I'm instructed to build a file structure that lists files recursively like this:

> ```
> Folder
> ----example.py
> ----NewDirectory
> --------folder
> ------------root.txt
> --------samplefile.txt
> ----NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk
> ----spse2.txt
> ```

The instructor seems to imply I don't need to use recursive functions but he did mention fnmatch and glob.
After reading the documentation and looking on forums, this is what I came up with (please bear my generous debug code):

```
import os
import fnmatch

def tree(path = ""):
    print(path)
    level = 1
    separator = "----" * level
    for file in os.listdir("." + path):
        print("Scanning files in " + path)
        print(os.listdir("." + path))

        if os.path.isfile(file):
            print("file found! It's called " + file)
            print(separator + file)
        elif os.path.isdir(file):
            print("dir found! It's called " + file)
            print(separator + file)
            level += 1
            print("Entering directory...")
            tree("/" + file)
        else:
            print(file + " is corrupted or of an unknown format.")

tree()
```

Output was:

> ```
> Scanning files in 
> ['example.py', 'NewDirectory', 'NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk', 'spse2.txt']
> file found! It's called example.py
> ----example.py
> Scanning files in 
> ['example.py', 'NewDirectory', 'NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk', 'spse2.txt']
> dir found! It's called NewDirectory
> ----NewDirectory
> Entering directory...
> /NewDirectory
> Scanning files in /NewDirectory
> ['folder', 'samplefile.txt']
> folder is corrupted or of an unknown format.
> Scanning files in /NewDirectory
> ['folder', 'samplefile.txt']
> samplefile.txt is corrupted or of an unknown format.
> Scanning files in 
> ['example.py', 'NewDirectory', 'NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk', 'spse2.txt']
> file found! It's called NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk
> ----NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk
> Scanning files in 
> ['example.py', 'NewDirectory', 'NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk', 'spse2.txt']
> file found! It's called spse2.txt
> ----spse2.txt
> ```

Can't seem to enter the folder 'folder'. What should I do here?

Thanks.

Comment: If you replace `def tree(path = "")` with `def tree(path)` and run(bottom of code) it by `tree("Folder")`,does it work?

Comment: "Folder" was actuallly called "Python Pentesting" so I changed it and implemented your changes, but I did get errors on line 8 when the "." gets concatenated to the path. Also, I tried putting the full path in `tree()` like `tree("C:\Users\Adrian\Desktop\Infosec\Notes\Python Pentesting")`, but that got me a Syntax error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your code:

Your recursion doesn't take in `level` as argument, so you increment it without results (as seen in your output).[Talking about `'---'`,`'-----'` incremental]

Here I refactored a little your code:

```
def tree(path='.', level=1):
    #print(path)
    #level=1
    separator = "----" * level
    #print("Scanning files in " + path)
    #print(f"content: {os.listdir(path)}")
    for each_item in os.listdir(path):
      #print('Checking item ',each_item)
      if os.path.isfile(path+f'/{each_item}'):
        #print("file found! It's called " + each_item)
        print(separator + each_item)
        pass
      elif os.path.isdir(path+f'/{each_item}'):
        #print("directory found! It's called " + each_item)
        print(separator + each_item)
        level+=1
        #print(f"Entering directory...{each_item}")
        tree(path+f'/{each_item}', level)
      else:
        print(f"{each_item} is corrupted or of an unknown format.")

tree()
```

Commented the most of the prints from within the function, remaining output:

```
----Folder
------------example.py
------------NewDirectory
----------------samplefile.txt
----------------folder
--------------------root.txt
------------NewDirectory - Shortcut.lnk
----initial.py
```

[Check online compiler.](https://repl.it/repls/MelodicDodgerblueDecimals)

One note on recursion with default values (default meaning `def function (argument=10)` ) you should check [this article out](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/).

On a second note, regarding `fnmatch` and `glob` ( and not `os.walk` from title).

For a defined structure as yours you could use the `fnmatch` to find files that have python (py) as extension (python files). Or texts (txt) and so on:

```
for file in os.listdir('.'):
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.py'):
        print(file)
```

Created a basic example of this take inside the compiler link (check `main2.py` file).

On a third note, check this Path constant from [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html) library:

```
from pathlib import Path

for path in Path('.').rglob('*'):
    print(path.name)
```